# Forge viewer display only part of element / node

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

we implemented a complex filter method to filter the elements of the model. Everything based on IFC. Following an example of a IfcFooting element with 2 sub-elements:

```
ID      IfcType                     Description
--------------------------------------------------------
1       IfcFooting                  Base
2       > IfcBuildingElementPart    Insulation
3       > IfcBuildingElementPart    Reinforced Concrete
```

The filter method can find IfcFooting elements with special sub-element "Reinforced Concrete". Return value is ID 1 and 3. In the viewer we are using the following method to display only the filter results:

```
viewer3d.impl.visibilityManager.hide(rootId, model);

$.each(selection, function (k, v) {
    viewer3d.impl.visibilityManager.show(v, model);
});
```

Problem is that calling this method with ID 1, the viewer will display 1, 2 and 3. Is it possible to disable this behaviour? We only need to display the sub-element 3, but it is not possible to ignore ID 1 in filter results... thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the expected behavior, if the id is not a leaf component but a logical component that owns children, then it's normal that showing/hiding this component will impact all its children.

What you should do is make sure all the ids you collect are leaf components (check that instanceTree.enumNodeChildren(dbId) has no children). And perform the logic on leaf only.

In your case you would filter out dbId 1 because it has children and only show dbId 3.

Here is an example:

```
 function isLeafComponent (dbId) {

  var instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree

  var childCount = 0

  instanceTree.enumNodeChildren(dbId, function(childId) {

    ++childCount
  })

  return (childCount < 2) // Handles IFC with "Body" child
}
```

Comment: Ok, yeah, this is because the hierarchy generated from IFC is different. With a .rvt file for example dbId 3 would have no child. So same approach but you need to check that the component is not 'Body' or has at least 2 children. If the component has only 1 child then you would not mind because no other unwanted component will be toggled as a result of setting visibility on the parent.